# Chrome kiosk mode and canvas to sign on touch screen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, kiosk-mode

I am developing an user interface where the users have to sign in a touch screen (using this [javascript](http://demo.jorgeivanmeza.com/JavaScript/DrawingCanvasDemo/0.1/functions.js)). Everythings goes fine on my pc, but on production screen, using the kiosk mode of chrome doesn´t work fine. The problem is that when I try to make a line inside the canvas, the kiosk mode try to "move" from the actual web page to the previous or nex page (the behaviour is similar than when you click on the arrows to move on the browser history of this tab). It only works if you try to paint with small dots.

I think that what I need is to do is capture the event with the canvas and don´t pass it to the browser... or something like that... really I don´t know. Any help?? Thanks

PS: I hope I made myself clear.